# convert an excel file to a blob in node

Tags: node.js, excel, blob, readfile

I ma reading in a local file, and want to convert it to a blob.

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('./mybook.xlsx', {encoding:'base64'});
const base64 = base64ToBlob(data)
const blob = new Blob(base64, {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
```

I am getting the error.

*Argument type Blob is not assignable to parameter type BlobPart[] | undefined   Type Blob is not assignable to type BlobPart[]     Type Blob is not assignable to type Array*

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
const fs = require('fs')

const data = fs.readFileSync('./mybook.xlsx', {encoding:'base64'})
const base64 = Buffer.from(data,"base64")
const blob = new Blob([base64], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' })
console.log(blob)
```

Output

```
$ node make-blob-js
Blob {
  size: 8723,
  type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
}
```